# Rails Access field values that are not from model on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-4, field

I have a form for some model, inside this form I have some text_fields and hidden_fields
that i need to use in the controller but that are not from the model.

this is a simplified version of it

```
<%= from_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= hidden_field :photo, value: 'blabla' %>
  <%= text_field :type %>
<% f.submit %>
```

Lets say that the :photo and :type parameters are not in the model user but i need them to decide how to create the user.

they are going in the params hash, but all messed up. How do I access their value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hidden_field_tag "photo", "photo_value"
=> <input id="photo" name="photo" type="hidden" value="photo_value" />
```

Then in your controller:

```
@hidden_photo = params[:photo]
```

Whenever you are working with a form and want a value not associated with a model or object, then use the helpers ending in "*_tag"